# GitHub API Branch Count

Tags: git-branch, github-api

I need to retrieve how many branches there are in a specified repository. If I call this

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches
```

I get the first 30, but I want them all

How do I tell the API to return everything? Or at least specify a different count to 30

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to pass

```
?per_page=100&page=1
```

in the URL. 100 records at a time is the maximum.

https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination